# Lazy evaluation in Ruby 2

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I recently installed Ruby 2.0.0 and found that it now has a [lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) method for the Enumerable mixin.  From previous experience in functional languages, I know that this makes for more efficient code.

I did a benchmark (*not sure if it is moot*) of lazy versus eager and found that lazy was continually faster.  Why is this?  What makes lazy evaluation better for large input?

Benchmark code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'

num = 1000
arr = (1..50000).to_a

Benchmark.bm do |rep|
    rep.report('lazy') { num.times do ; arr.lazy.map { |x| x * 2 }; end }
    rep.report('eager') { num.times do ; arr.map { |x| x * 2}; end }
end
```

Benchmark report sample:

```
       user     system      total        real
lazy  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.009502)
eager  5.550000   0.480000   6.030000 (  6.231269)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's so lazy it's not even doing the work - probably because you're not actually using the results of the operation.  Put a `sleep()` in there to confirm:

```
> Benchmark.bm do |rep|
    rep.report('lazy')    { num.times do ; arr.lazy.map { |x| sleep(5) }; end }
    rep.report('notlazy') { 1.times do   ; [0,1].map { |x| sleep(5) }   ; end }
  end

         user     system      total        real
lazy     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.007130)
notlazy  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 10.001788)
```

Comment: I used `map!` and got that lazy was around 9 times faster.  I might update my question's report, since you're right saying it doesn't change anything.